# Apache2 [Errno 13] Permission denied error

Tags: apache2

Within my VirtualHost apache2 config file I have:

```
<Directory /var/www/antiques/media>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And yet when I'm trying to load an image I'm getting the following error:
    [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/antiques/media/categories'

What am I missing?

Comment: What are the file permissions in that directory?

Comment: Doesn't `Require all granted` set the file permissions?

Comment: No, the user under which apache is running must have at least read permissions on that directory. You can check the permissions by running ls -al in the /var/www/antiques/media directory.

Comment: permissions are: `drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Aug 18 11:32 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root  4096 Aug 18 11:32 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 21414 Aug 18 11:32 image_not_found.jpg`

Comment: How do I give a program the permissions?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure how to give permission to file or folder, install FileZilla and connect to your server. Then just go right click on file/folder and find file permissions option. There you can change file/folder permissions much easier.

Define the requirements

```
Developers need read/write access to files so they can update the website
Developers need read/write/execute on directories so they can browse around
Apache needs read access to files and interpreted scripts
Apache needs read/execute access to serveable directories
Apache needs read/write/execute access to directories for uploaded content
```

Check out this [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/357108/what-permissions-should-my-website-files-folders-have-on-a-linux-webserver) for more info about werbserver permissions.

Comment: I know how to use chmod but I don't know how to set it so that only the program has access (irrespective of user) and no one can get in via some other backdoor route of which I'm not aware

Comment: @HenryM Check out my answer now.